# android fragment inside dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an issue where I need to show a `fragment` in a `android.app.Dialog`

here is the xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/marchecharts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

what I want is to replace `marchecharts` by my fragment, can anyone help

thanks

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.marche_charts_parent);


//this is the part I think I need
Fragment fragment = new MarcheChartsFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity) dialog.getOwnerActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.marchecharts, fragment);  
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();

dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually you directly use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) which name is self explained.

here is an example of my code with an `int` send as arg.

So basically you create a `DialogFragment` which extends `DialogFragment`.
You have to write `newInstance` and `onCreateDialog` methods.
Then you create a new instance of that fragment in the calling fragment.

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public static YourDialogFragment newInstance(int myIndex) {
        YourDialogFragment yourDialogFragment = new YourDialogFragment();

        //example of passing args
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("anIntToSend", myIndex);
        yourDialogFragment.setArguments(args);

        return yourDialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //read the int from args
        int myInteger = getArguments().getInt("anIntToSend");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        //here read the different parts of your layout i.e :
        //tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
        //tv.setText("some text")

        return view;
    }
}
```

calling the dialog fragment is done from another fragment by doing this.
Note that the value `0` is the int I send.

```
YourDialogFragment yourDialogFragment = YourDialogFragment.newInstance(0);
YourDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "DialogFragment");
```

In your case if you don't need to pass anything, remove the corresponding lines in the DialogFragment and don't pass any value in the `YourDialogFragment.newInstance()`

**EDIT/FOLLOW**

Not sure to really understand your question.
If you simply need to replace a fragment by another you use

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_fragment_container, new YourFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: thank you for your response!

i got an error in onCreateDialog: Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to Dialog at "return view" line

Comment: at second thoughts, I dont think this answers the problem, because I already have a fragment in hand I just need to show it in a dialog

Comment: As far as I understand your question. You want to display your own fragment in a dialog. If that is your question the code I provide adresse that.

Comment: thanks you, you basicly gave me a hint of what i need, i had a fragment which  I needed to show on phone as a normal fragment, but on tablet as a dialog, so I ended up extending my own fragment from DialogFragment, wich works great so far